# Python Django migration error

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1553, "Cannot drop index 'star_ratings_userrating_user_id_5a83a88db79dd2cf_uniq': needed in a foreign key constraint")
```

[image: Screen Shot]

I have installed an application in my project django-star-ratings 0.5.3. It requires syncing database and when I migrate python manage.py migrate it shows an error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Drop the tables in the opposite order.

Comment: I am a newbie to Django.. Can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: The error is from the database, not django, as far as I understand... just reverse the lines ... you're trying to drop something that is dependent on something else.. so drop that something else first.